# In Little Shop of Horrors, how is Audrey II able to see and hear?

Tags: little-shop-of-horrors

In *Little Shop of Horrors*, particularly the musical, Audrey II seems to be able to see and hear without having any visible eyes or ears.  How does the plant do this?

Comment: The same way she can speak without having a larynx or lungs.

Comment: If he can talk and he can move, who's to say he can't do anything he wants?